# Why is my instance property undefined when used in a class method?

Tags: javascript, instance-variables, es6-class

When trying to run `cow1.voice();` and I keep getting an error in the console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: type is not defined

```
class Cow {
  constructor(name, type, color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.color = color;
  };
  voice() {
    console.log(`Moooo ${name} Moooo ${type} Moooooo ${color}`);
  };
};

const cow1 = new Cow('ben', 'chicken', 'red');
```

Comment: The reason why it fails on `type` instead of `name` is because `name` is referring to [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). (This doesn't answer the question, but might still be useful to know.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`type` and others are instance variables of your class, so you need to use `this` to access them. The initial variables `name`, `type`, `color`, provided to the constructor are used for class initialisation and aren't available outside of constructor.

```
class Cow {
  constructor(name, type, color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.color = color;
  };

  voice() {
    // Access instance vars via this
    console.log(`Moooo ${this.name} Moooo ${this.type} Moooooo ${this.color}`);
  };
};
```

Comment: Yes but when i run cow1.voice() in the console i am getting the error and not the templated string?

Comment: That's because the variable is not defined, you need to use `this.type`

Comment: Can you send me a updated snippet of code so i can see were i am going wrong?

Comment: @BenJohnson What do you mean? The correct code is in the answer.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say instance variables "are not available outside of the constructor". They're available, but only on `this`.

Comment: @RobertStiffler really good point, I've mixed up variables used for initialization and instance variables there. I've updated the answer.